# How correctly store data with laravel vue axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to send data to database from a vue component.

The vue component

```
                ...<form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Nom de la tache</label>
                        <textarea name="name" id="name" rows="4" class="form-control" v-model="name"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>...


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            name: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        taskStore() {
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/taskStore', {
                name: this.name,
            })
                .then(response => console.log(response))
                .catch(error => console.log('une erreur '+error));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

the road

```
Route::post('/taskStore', 'TaskController@store');
```

and the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Task::create($request);
    }
```

Please someone saw what's i'm doing wrong ? 
I got this error and i can't found why for moment.
thanks by advance

Comment: "I got this error" What error, what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To add to AWEMA Agence Web Marketing's answer above (since I can't add comments yet)

You'll also need to ensure the `name` attribute on your `Task` model is fillable

```
class Task extends Model {

   protected $fillable = ['name'];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just forget to add ->all() after $request in my store function...

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Task::create($request->all());
    }
```